Help identifying privacy door knob
Bit of a longshot but the knob in the pictures broke (push button fell out) and I'm trying to find a replacement online but without much luck. On one side of the knob it has F605-238 and the other side of the knob has F605-248 so hoping someone might know it. Closest thing I can find online is a Schlage Orbit privacy knob but the thing throwing me off really is the colour.
If anyone is able to confirm what the model number is and the colour that would be great.
Thanks







Think the finish might be called brush bronze.

Lock sets are available in a wide range of it finishes. There is a standard numbering system which theoretically should help you find the closest equivalent in any given brand once you have identified what the finish is that you are trying to match. A locksmith may have samples you can compare against, or you can try carrying the old knob into your favorite big box store and comparing it to what they have on the shelves.
